# How to keep filter and current page when updating PrimeFaces dataTable

Tags: primefaces, filter, datatable

I have a data table which has paginator and a filter. When the table is filtered and not at the first page and I try to remove a row, I want to keep both the filter and the current page. So I tried something like this:

```
  try {
            List<Vector> filteredData = incomeTable.getFilteredValue();
            Map<String, Object> filterValue = incomeTable.getFilters();
            if (filteredData == null) {
                filteredData = lstData;
            }

            int index = filteredData.indexOf(selectedRow);
            lstData.remove(selectedRow);
            filteredData.remove(selectedRow);
            if (filteredData.size() > index) {
                selectedRow = filteredData.get(index);
            } else {
                selectedRow = filteredData.get(index - 1);
            }
            onRowSelect();
            incomeTable.setFilteredValue(filteredData);
            incomeTable.setFilters(filterValue);
            incomeTable.setFirst(getFirstRecordShow(filteredData));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            reportException(e);
        }
```

After this function is processed, I update the table on the client side:

```
update="@([id$=incomeTable])"
```

I was able to keep the current page, list of filtered data and display the selected row correctly. But the filter I used on the header rows was cleared. I already tried

```
incomeTable.setFilters(filterValue);
```

to set the value again, but it's still not working.

Does anyone know how to keep both filter and the current page in this case?

My PrimeFaces version is 5.3.

Comment: @Jasper de Vries : you didn't read all of my requiredment in this case? i want to keep the current page, so both clearFilters or filter aren't acceptable because they will move paginator back to first page.

Comment: OK. I improved your question. I'll have a look later.

Comment: Why not just refrain from updating the datatable and just use an ajax call to remove the row server side and use some simple jquery on the on complete of the ajax call to remove it client-side? No need to filter or whatever. Only small downside is that the page now contains 'rows-1' rows.

Comment: @Kukeltje : how to remove row on client side ? PF('incomeTable') doesn't have any remove function aside from removeSelection. Also if i try to remove it from view by deleting whole <tr/> element, my table's index column won't get update so there will be a missing index right?

Comment: Does the 'missing' index cause a problem?

Comment: @Kukeltje : Not a problem with code but with our tester and customer. They won't let it pass :(

Comment: Why would a customer not let it pass? Or the tester?  Just because there is one row less in the datatable? Or due to the **technical** issue of the index missing one record?

Comment: @Kukeltje : If you delete it by javascript, for example line 18. Since table not update again, the index column not re-index by itself, so it will be index 17 then 19, no 18 between. And it not call that index any longer.

Comment: Yes, and how is that a **problem**... it IS removed... If it is also removed server side, there might not be a problem. Only if you try and state that:  "If I implement it like this and after removing a row I do such and so I get an error that I normally not get", there is a problem.

Comment: @Kukeltje : You don't understand ? or you just dont want to understand ? I already said that it not a problem with code but interface. If a table have a mising index like that, it will be log as interface bug and tester as well as our customer will ask us to re-index the column, which will involve update whole table.

Comment: I hear/understand what you say, but imo it can never be a testing requirement that an index is missing. That is a technical implementation by PF and might change over time and all your tests will fail and your testers will complain that you messed it up while you didn't. So I still don'[ t see the missing index as a problem. The only requirement that might prevent this solution is that there should always be the maximum amount of records available according to page size. But on the last page that will also not be true... Hence... I see my solution/proposal as a valid one.

Comment: And if the index is a business visible column (I might have misunderstood then), then yes, a record is missing, but reloading with the same filter/sorting will only add a record at the end of the page. Still not a real problem according to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, the result turn out to be rather simple.

Just like toggle column visible while using paging (using boolean[]), create a String[] which will hold all the filter value

```
private String[] colVisible = new String[] {"", "", "", "", ...};
```

Add filterValue attribute to every column:

```
<p:column headerText="Header text"
    filterBy="#{item[1]}" filterMatchMode="contains"
    visible="#{bean.colVisible[1]}"
    filterValue="#{bean.filterValue[1]}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item[1]}" />
</p:column>
```

This way the filter value will be keep even after update. Then when i need to clear filter, i just need to reset all of them back to blank.

Comment: Cool, nice solution. Out of curiosity, did you try with 6.0 to? If I remember correctly some things have changed in this regard between 5.3 and 6.0. Small nitpick: should colVisible not be filterValue  (and privagte private ;-))

Comment: @Kukeltje : I havent try with 6.0 yet since our PM doesn't give us permission to upgrade until we finish our development phase, but maybe when maintain this website. About colVisible, it for display or hidden column. When you use p:columnToggler with paginator, if you change page, primeface table keep number of column header you choose to display but each row display all column instead. So it make header and row value mismatch.